# How can I log into a commandline session, without having to launch any desktop environment?

Tags: command-line, login, battery, desktop-environments, tty

In an effort to preserve battery, I'd like to have a session type of just the commandline at login.

- I do not want root.
- I do not want to login to gnome and then switch to a ttyl, as I would still be running a DE in the background.

I just want to boot my computer to the login prompt, select from the session types a commandline option, and then login to that where no desktop environment is running.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

To go back to graphical boot:

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Answer (score 0):

Are search something like this?

create a grub-skript in /etc/grub.d (example name) /etc/grub.d/70_text-mode

To long for answerblock [paste](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f8kC8VXz4v/)

I coppied  /etc/grub.d/10_linux
and make some changes for me.

you can set other variable irrespective of /etc/default/grub

Make the skript executable and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Oh I forget this part

```
export GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='systemd.unit=multi-user.target'
```

boots in multi-user.target (earlier named text-mode) all services are starting besides display-manger and gui.